# what protocol to I need to allow in firewall in order to connect from python to apache spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, devops, firewall, amazon-emr

I am using python with pyspark and using spark context in order to connect to the master using [these](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/spark-standalone.html) ports

We are starting to use amazon EMR and with to open the correct ports in the firewall in order to connect to the cluster from outside the VPC.

We will open ports 7077 for the master connection and 8080 for the webui.
But what communication protocols should we allow? We would like to be protocol selective and not allow all protocols.

Answer (score 0):

Protocol should be TCP as calls are plain HTTP(s) rest stuff

Comment: How work streaming video website? stream should be UDP but website is TCP

Comment: it heavily depends on the protocol (dvb's HLS stuff maybe?) and the stuff that you want to send to spark, i havent streamed video directly to spark though, not sure if that's a thing-